# Connect to YouTube API using Server token

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using successfully the below code to connect to YouTube API:

```
public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";
public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = GoogleSheetImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret_json");

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
    DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
}

private static YouTube youtube;

@Test
public void test() {

    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

    try {
        Credential credential = authorize(scopes, "commentthreads");

        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-playlistupdates-sample")
                .build();

        process();

    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But as you can see it uses OAuth to authenticate which opens web page and asks me to loginto my Google account.

Is there some way to use the Server-to-Server token? For the token I won't need to load web page to authenticate. Is there some tutorial how to configure the connection factory properly?

Answer (score 1):

Not all Google apis support service accounts.  The YouTube api is one of the APIs that does not support service account authentication.

You will need to use Oauth2 to authenticate a user then save a refresh token you can then use that refresh token to request a new access token.

Comment: Is there some way to use the API without opening a web page and every time sign-in the user? I need a way to do several calls from different users from a Linux server. I don't have the option to open a web page.

Comment: Yes you do as i stated and authenticate it once store the refresh token (upload it to the server with your code) then you will be able to use the refresh token to request a new access token when ever you need.   You shouldn't need to authenticate it again as long as you have that refresh token.

Comment: I found one blocking issues. I can authenticate maximum 10 accounts in Google Sign-In page. Is there some way to authenticate more?

Comment: Your using a service account not google signin this does not effect you.

Comment: the is the main issue -> I can't use service account for YouTube Java Api because only Sign-In via web interface is supported. I can't find a solution to use Sign-In via refresh token.